# Open quote is expected for attribute "src" associated with an element type "script"

Tags: javascript, html, xml, blogger, saxparseexception

Sam this side, currently I was working on my sites code . I thought of adding a loading animation in the site , but after adding adding the code it is giving me a strange error whose solution can't be found anywhere

code containing the line which caused this nuisance `

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:css='false' b:defaultwidgetversion='2' b:layoutsVersion='3' b:responsive='true' b:templateUrl='fancy.xml' b:templateVersion='1.3.3' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:lang='data:blog.locale' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>
    
<script src=<”//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js”><\/script>

<script type=”text/javascript”>

$(window).load(function() {

$(“.loader”).fadeOut(“slow”);

})

</script>
```

**THE ERROR WHICH I GET WHEN TRY TO SAVE THE THEME**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 13; Open quote is expected for attribute "src" associated with an element type "script".
```

**SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR:**

[image]

I have given the link as I am not allowed to embed images yet

*pls tell me if you need more code*

Pls help me out with this, your help will be very appreciated

**Thanks in advance**

EDIT :

[SEE THE SECOND IMAGE WHICH I TOOK AFTER EDIT THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O4eB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says **Open quote is expected for attribute "src" associated with an element type "script"**. You should change :

```
<script src=<”//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js”><\/script>
```

to :

```
<script src=”//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
```

(remove the '<' character after '=', and `<\/script> to </script>`)

Also, you should change ” to ".

Comment: I tried your suggested edit, but after editing the code I am still getting the same error

Comment: THANKS AFTER CHANGING  ( ” ) to ( " ) this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Change it with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:css='false' b:defaultwidgetversion='2' b:layoutsVersion='3' b:responsive='true' b:templateUrl='fancy.xml' b:templateVersion='1.3.3' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:lang='data:blog.locale' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>
<script src=//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
```

It's seems like you wrong using double quotes.

Comment: I TRIED THIS ALSO BUT STILL, THE ERROR IS PRESENT